# Using .p8 certificate in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub, p8

I am attempting to configure a `Notification Hub` for APNS in Azure Portal. There are two options: `Certificate` and `Token`. The certificate option is redundant as it only takes p12 certifcates and Apple now only does p8 certificates.

For the Token option, I am presented with the following fields: `Key Id`, `Bundle Id`, `Team Id`, and `Token`.

I have already created a p8 certificate, and have entered the values for all the above fields except the `Token` field. Where do I get the token? Is it the `private key` that is contained in the p8 certificate?

**Update**

According to Microsoft, Token refers to the key or private key 'obtained from the p.8 file': [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, Token refers to the key or private key 'obtained from the p.8 file': [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification)

Comment: Yes - this is correct. It's that actual secret string from within the .p8 file.